# Web Scraping using list comprehension

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I can definitely provide more information and the HTML blocks in question if needed.   I'd like to be able to transform the following block into a list comprehension using the `find_all` command rather than just the `find` command:

```
soup.find(class_ = 'info-box').find_parent().find('p').text
```

When I try to do it myself using the following:

```
[p.text for p in soup.find_all(class_= 'info-box').find_parent().find('p')]
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find_parent'
```

Comment: Please provide some sample HTML: are there multiple <p> elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are applying `find_parent()` to the whole `ResultSet` instead of the individual element. You can try the following:

```
[p.find_parent().find('p').text for p in soup.find_all(class_= 'info-box')]
```

Comment: gotcha, I was trying something similar but I could get the attribute order of the iterator correct.  This is perfect, thank you!